# KeyboardAvoidingView not working properly with behaviour position

Tags: javascript, react-native

The problem is simple to understand when I click inside the search bar everything goes up, check the images below to understand my problem

```js
<KeyboardAvoidingView 
    behavior='position'>
    // code here
</KeyboardAvoidingView >
```

Before

[image]

After I click on the search bar, basically, everything goes up

[image]

Answer (score 0):

its just android thing. so what you need to do is

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView
  behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? "padding" : null} enabled
  style={{ flex: 1,  }}>

  // your content

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```